My icons for my button are not appearing when i run my app
I am developing a WPF app which functions properly. My only problem is with the buttons that contain icons. When i run the app, the buttons appear just fine but not the images (icon) that I have added in them- it's just a plain button. I know i dont have to do this but i want to be fancy. thank you.
here is my code:
<Button Width="52" Margin="0,0,0,5" Height="30" Click="BackBtn_Click">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Image Source="/Models/back_arrow.png" Width="16" Height="16"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>

code for the second button:
<Button x:Name="OpenFilterWindow" Width="70" Margin="15,0,0,0" Height="30" Click="OpenFilterWindow_Click">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Image Source="/Models/filter.png" Height="16" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>

essentially, there is a filter button that contains a filter icon and a 'Back to menu' button which is supposed to have an arrow but these icons do not appear when i run the app, only when i am viewing my xaml code. Some help on how to fix this would be much appreciated!

Make sure that the image files are located in a Project Folder named Models in your Visual Studio Project and that their Build Action is set to Resource.

Besides that, it is unclear what the purpose of the StackPanels is. You could assign the Image elements directly to the Buttons' Content.

@Clemens I appreciate the help. The Stackpanel was there because i initially wanted to add some text next to the icon, thinking it would reveal them , i removed the text to no avail. Ended up removing the Stackpanel too, like you suggested and that still didn't work :(....decided to add some text for now.

The StackPanel has nothing to with your problem. You have to set the correct Build Action for the image files, as said before.

You may also want to take a look at Segoe MDL2 Assets icons and write <Button FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE71C;"/> for the Filter Button and <Button FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Content="&#xE72B;"/> for the Back Button.
